# Nuxt js Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Good day to you! Just started to study Nuxtjs and Vue and encountered such a problem, when the page is initially loaded everything is displayed normally, but once I reboot it, I get a maximum stack size exceeded error. I realized that the problems arose because of the `asyncData` function, but what I’m doing is wrong to understand. Please tell me where I was wrong.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <h1>USERS</h1>

        <ul>
            <li v-for="user of getusers.data" :key="user.id" >
               <a href="#" @click.prevent="openUser(user.id)">{{ user.name }}</a>    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
     async asyncData ({$axios}) {
        const getusers = await $axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        
        return {getusers}
    },
     data: () => ({
      getusers: []  
    }),
    methods: {
        openUser(user) {
            this.$router.push('/users/' + user
            )
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[image "my error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHvlu.png)

Comment: seems okey are you sure this is the error cas?

Comment: Yeah, there’s a bug here that links to the screen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uMR6CYUCWjureIzRfwn3k5hMRIO_Qs2j/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. Forgot to put a $ sign before get and fix the cycle for.

```
   const getusers = await $axios.$get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
```

v-for="user of getusers"

Comment: The missing `$` on the `get` was my issue as well, surprisingly. Why does this matter? In other contexts, I use just plain get with no $. In hindsight, those contexts are front-end only, whereas my get was in a fetch() and occurred server-side. So, perhaps axios on server-side is sensitive and needs `$get`?

Comment: From the Nuxt Axios docs, you do indeed need to use `$get` when on server-side (whether through `fetch()` or `asyncdata()`: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#-shortcuts